# compute the integral: $\int\frac{x^2-1}{x^4-4x^2-1} dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to compute the integral $$\int\frac{x^2-1}{x^4-4x^2-1} dx.$$

I tried to use partial fractions technique but I got $3$ difficult terms which I don't know how to compute them.

**ATTEMPT**: wolfram gives this partial fractions but even then how can i integrate them?
btw i didn't get them without wolfram. it was too diffcult for me.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2-1%29%2F%28x%5E4-4x%5E2-1%29+partial+fractions

Comment: Please write your attempt here!

Comment: I did the integral using Mathematica and it certainly does not look like a "simple and pleasing" result.  But, guessing in the form of the answer, the key looks like an approach using partial fractions and then after that try trigonometric substitutions.

Comment: I'm curious. Where did you find this integral?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2-1%29%2F%28x%5E4-4x%5E2-1%29+partial+fractions

Comment: Since the denominator has two real roots, partial fractions should yield something of the form $\frac{A}{x-r_1} + \frac{B}{x-r_2} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2+bx+c}$. The first two should be easy. For the third one, complete the square in the denominator; let's say you get $(x-v)^2 + k$. Then $\frac{Cx+D}{(x-v)^2+k} = \frac{C(x-v)}{(x-v)^2+k} + \frac{Cv+D}{(x-v)^2+k}$. Then take $u=x-v$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify the solution by considering partial fractions expansion
$$\frac{t-1}{t^2-4t-1}=\frac{a}{t+(\sqrt5-2)}+\frac{b}{t-(\sqrt5+2)},$$
where $$a=\frac{5-\sqrt5}{10},\quad b=\frac{5+\sqrt5}{10}.$$
Then your integral is
$$I=a\int\frac{dx}{x^2+(\sqrt5-2)}+b\int\frac{dx}{x^2-(\sqrt5+2)}=$$
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}}\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}}+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}}\log\left|\frac{x-\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}}{x+\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}}\right|+C.$$